# Why do I need to explicitly add files (instead of just committing them)?

Tags: svn, addition, commit

Why do I need to explicitly `add` a file to SVN and *then* `commit` it? Isn't it obvious if someone is committing a file that has not been added to SVN, then they want to add it to SVN? What is the benefit of having an explicit `add` step?

Comment: So if I use an editor that creates .bak files those should be added and committed automatically? Or do you *force* them to add an ignore?

Comment: I think he's asking why must you use `svn add foo.c; svn commit foo.c` rather than just `svn commit foo.c`.  Putting the filename explicitly in the commit command makes this a good question to me.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the benefit of having an explicit add step?

You may add several files one by one using `svn add` command and then commit all of them from root folder of working copy by one command `svn commit`. This may be convenient sometimes.

Comment: But wouldn't it be easier if I just do a `commit` from the root directory and thats it? Why do I need to `add` the files? Doesn't the `commit` imply I want to add them?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Working copies are often full of all sorts of files that you specifically *do not* want checked in (intermediate object files, compiled binaries, etc). It is important to be able to commit all changes to tracked files without having those unwanted files automatically checked in.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg You may have modifications in 8 different files, but only 4 of them are ready to be committed yet... For example, if you're working on a new feature, but it's not finished yet, but you get sidetracked to fix a critical bug in a different file...

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Than you will have to commit new files like this: `svn commit probably_long_files_list`. This is probably not easier than just `svn commit`.

Comment: @AndrewMedico But these files are generally stuffed into known directories. wouldn't it be easier to ignore those directories and auto-add everything else?

Comment: @twalberg Thats why you don't commit from root ever, but that applies even with the current add logic, so its not really relevant to this.